# C# send arrow keys to a Proccess

Tags: c#

I am using the following code to run a programme, while I'm able to send it key presses for letters, space as  and `\n` for enter. However I am unable to send the arrow keys, since they have no ASCII value.

```
string yourApp = "C:\\program";
ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
processInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
processInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
processInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
processInfo.WorkingDirectory = yourApp;
processInfo.Arguments = "/c abcdef";

Process cmd = Process.Start(processInfo);

cmd.StandardInput.Write(" "); // press space
cmd.StandardInput.Flush();

cmd.StandardInput.Write("\n"); // press enter
cmd.StandardInput.Flush();

cmd.StandardInput.Write("a"); // press a
cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
```

any ideas?

Comment: Redirecting the non-typing keys, like the function and arrow keys is not possible.  You'll need to tell a *lot* more about the program you are trying to automate to have any chance for getting useful help.

Comment: @HansPassant what useful data can I provide, other than `exe` itself

Answer (score 0):

If you're other process is a window, you could use [`SendMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`PostMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944(v=vs.85).aspx) to put an arrow key event message into the message queue of a window used in the other process.  This would simulate the actual keyboard arrow key event in the other process instead of going through `StandardInput`.  It will not be trivial.

[PInvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/) is a good resource for finding the necessary signatures for the unmanaged Windows APIs you'll have to use.  You'll first have to identify the correct Window handle in the other process, then initialize the necessary event parameters and call `SendMessage` (synchronous) or `PostMessage` (asynchronous).